# Can I use polymer clay to make a mold and then melt HDPE plastic in it in the oven?

Tags: plastic, molding

Can I use polymer clay to make a mold and then melt HDPE plastic in it in the oven? My goal is to be able to dig a fairly uncomplicated shape in a polymer clay block and then fill that mold with small HDPE plastic filaments. I'm hoping that the melted plastic would fill the mold with the help of gravity pushing it down or I can get it out to apply pressure a few times. Will the polymer clay melt? Do I have to bake it beforehand? If clay doesn't work, what other easily found and cheap substitute exists? Thank you.

Comment: How will you get the product out? What is the working or melting temperature of polymer clay - is it suitable?

Comment: @SolarMike Polymer clay is an oven-hardening art clay that gets slightly softer as it warms up but begins to solidify and harden when it reaches about 130°F (55°C). So it makes sense to harden it first alone in the oven and then add the plastic filaments. I will get the product out with a knife I suppose. Sorry, I don't know what you mean by the first question.